# Can my asp.net dll's or pages can be affected by virus living in my pc

Tags: asp.net, javascript, visual-studio-2008, virus

Just curious to know that if my PC is infected with a Trojan or any other virus, is it possible that my website will be infected along with that I have made up in asp.net with visual studio 2008.

I am not sure that it is the right place to put this question or shall I have to put it to 
https://stackapps.com/ or any other site linked to stackoverflow. But anyhow it is very important for me to know the answer.

Because one gentleman report me about the infection of `Jquery-1.2.3.min.js` which I have downloaded from JQuery official website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, any executable code can be infected by a virus. A .dll file could be infected by any virus, but whether that'll have an adverse effect on your website depends on the virus. A virus that purposefully infects web sites might, for instance, try to install malware on visitors' computers. This could potentially be done by infecting any file that has executable code, from an .aspx file to a JavaScript file.

Personally I haven't heard of such a virus, but that doesn't mean they don't exist.

Comment: Thanks Matti, but as per the information I got AVG detected a visrus JS:Illredir-CB [Trj] on javascript file, which indicate that it's a Trojan virus. So, is their any way I can get rid of these kind of viruses in future.

Thanks again for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a false alarm:
http://forum.avira.de/wbb/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=88834

Report it to the gentleman/Antivirus manufacturer

Comment: Is their any way I can get rid of these kinds of effects in future

Comment: As  mentioned in my link you should(f.e. for Antivir):
If you think AntiVir has detected a clean file by mistake, the only way to correct this false detection is to move the detection to quarantine and then send the file to Avira Virus Lab  and to select "Suspected False Positive (Not Malware)" from the drop down menu for File type. You will receive a complete report from the Lab.
If false positive is confirmed, it will be removed in a future VDF release.